# Can I create datatype property for particular class in OWL?

Tags: rdf, owl, semantic-web

Something like..
Suppose I have a class named Instructor.

Now, I need to have a datatypeProperties linked only to instructor like salary, instructor_name..

What is the RDF structure for this? Is such thing possible?

Comment: Try `rdfs:domain` as a first step.

Comment: I guess you're mixing up datatypes and properties...

Comment: I meant to say dataTypeProperties actually..

Comment: @StanislavKralin rdfs:domain works.. Thanks Mate!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Adding rdfs:domain works!

```
<!-- Define the salary property -->
<owl:DatatypeProperty rdf:about="http://www.example.com/sample#salary">
    <rdfs:domain rdf:resource="http://www.example.com/sample#instructor" />
</owl:DatatypeProperty>
```